# Cómo obtener el valor de un return en javascript

Tags: javascript

Cómo puedo obtener el valor del return en otra function o en la función que envía la suma

```js
opera(1,2,3);

function opera(sum1, sum2, sum3) {

let sum = sum1 + sum2 + sum3;

return sum;

}
```

Comment: Ya lo estás recibiendo, si imprimes por consola o un alert la llamada `opera(1,2,3);` se imprimirá el resultado obtenido...

Comment: El `return` ya está funcionando, lo que no estás haciendo es guardar o usar el resultado. Por ejemplo, con `const resultado = opera(1, 2, 3);` puedes guardar el resultado en la variable `resultado` y usarla como una variable cualquiera.

Answer (score 0):

Haciendo la misma asignación que haces en la propia function

```
let suma = opera(1,2,3);
alert(suma);

function opera(sum1, sum2, sum3) {

let sum = sum1 + sum2 + sum3;

return sum;

}
```